# Why blink bulb animation not working in Broadcast Receiver called from a Fragment

Tags: android-studio, animation, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My Alarm is getting triggered,This I confirmed by using debug statement in Broadcast receiver class.But blinking animation is not working.I am very new to Android.Can anyone tell me what is the issue?One guess i can get is may be Broadcast receiver is not able to know about fragment reference so it is not able to run the animation.If this is the case ,then actually I dont know to how to add the reference Or If I can return from the receiver and do all the activity inside the fragment.Please let me know the steps.

Fragement Scetion Code:

```
    Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,42);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(),NotificationActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id",R.id.notification_imageView);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent =  
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    System.out.println("DEBUG==> Instantiating Alarm Manager Service");
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 
    02,pendingIntent);
```

BroadcastReceiever Class --ClassNotificationActivity.class

```
  public class NotificationActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private View view;
  @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   ImageView img;
    System.out.println("DEBUG==> Page Notification Activity is being loaded");
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.Samplelayout, null);
   img = view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
   System.out.println("DEBUG==> Loading bulb Image for Animation"+img);
   System.out.println("DEBUG==> Loading bulb Image for Animation");
   Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.5, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to 
    invisible
    animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second--2 minutes
    animation.setRepeatCount(200);
    img.startAnimation(animation);
      }
         }
```

Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM" />

 <receiver  android:name=".view.ui.NotificationActivity" />
```

Samplelayout.xml:

```
       <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/Dumble"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="32dp" />


            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could please anyone can help in this?

Comment: can anyone tell me how to apply handler here to send a message from broadcaster to Fragment?